# Is there an OR/M for Classic ASP?

Tags: orm, asp-classic

Is there an OR/M (object relational mapper) that can be used in Classic ASP? Even a simplified class object would be a great help in handling simple CRUD tasks.

Yes I know ASP.NET has many and I use a few of them for ASP.NET sites. However this is a legacy e-commerce site that uses ASP/VBScript and a total rewrite it not a possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use .net through COM Interop, and do your ORM in .net. Another option would be to use [Code Smith](http://www.codesmithtools.com), or [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/) and generate VB6 classes.

Here's some VB6 ORM I have not used or researched any of these: 
http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/features.html

If I find anymore Ill update

Comment: No problem your best bet is still build the stuff in .net and use interop, this will start you on the path to migration. I would recommend you try and build everything in .net actually and use various bridging techniques. We had a classic asp app which was a beast but was able to bring .net to various backend systems and even the front end (Through IFrames)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing stopping you from using C# or VB.Net and COM Interop to create a DLL that could be read by your classic ASP page.  We have done that several times.

MSDN has two good tutorials on [COM Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645712(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Try my project called Clapper. Its available on Github. https://github.com/jeremychild/Clapper

Answer (score 0):

I also created a framework, but not is so strong than some frameworks said above,
is a simple but very useful framework and helped me a lot.

It's here:
https://github.com/FelipeNathan/asp-orm

and it's in portuguese

Answer (score -3):

I think IMVHO that ORM is a good choice for small projects but I prefer the easy and direct ODBC connections for larger ones.

All the (good) features of the ORMs can be provided by good RDBMS like Oracle or SQL Server.